# Flair en-sentiment model loading fails when not connected to the internet

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, flair

The following code fails for me when I do not have a working internet connection, with the error message that I have detailed below. I have tried a lot of things including configuring and checking the `.flair` folder and the `.cache` folder that the `transformers` package uses. I also checked that `distilbert-base-uncased` is a current model identifier on https://huggingface.co/models as the error message suggested. What can I do to fix this? Details below.

**Code that fails**

```
from flair.models import TextClassifier
en_classifier = TextClassifier.load('en-sentiment')
```

**Error:**

```
Can't load tokenizer for 'distilbert-base-uncased'. Make sure that:

- 'distilbert-base-uncased' is a correct model identifier listed on 'https://huggingface.co/models'

- or 'distilbert-base-uncased' is the correct path to a directory containing relevant tokenizer files
```

**Additional Details:**

Flair version: `0.8.0.post1'`

Environment variables needed because my app needs to run standalone with no internet connection:

```
TRANSFORMERS_OFFLINE=1
HF_DATASETS_OFFLINE=1
```

I have the model files located in the `.flair` directory that is configured by `flair.cache_root`. The code that works for me when I load other models is:

```
from flair.models import TextClassifier
rnn_classifier = TextClassifier.load('sentiment-fast')
```

even this works:

```
from flair.models import SequenceTagger
tagger = SequenceTagger.load('ner')
```

`.flair` directory has:

- `sentiment-en-mix-distillbert_4.pt`
- `sentiment-en-mix-ft-rnn.pt`
- `ner-english` (folder)
- `pos-english` (folder)

`~/.cache/huggingface/transformers` directory has:

- `0e1bbfda7f63a99bb52e3915dcf10c3c92122b827d92eb2d34ce94ee79ba486c.d789d64ebfe299b0e416afc4a169632f903f693095b4629a7ea271d5a0cf2c99`
- `0e1bbfda7f63a99bb52e3915dcf10c3c92122b827d92eb2d34ce94ee79ba486c.d789d64ebfe299b0e416afc4a169632f903f693095b4629a7ea271d5a0cf2c99.json`
- `75abb59d7a06f4f640158a9bfcde005264e59e8d566781ab1415b139d2e4c603.7f2721073f19841be16f41b0a70b600ca6b880c8f3df6f3535cbc704371bdfa4`
- `75abb59d7a06f4f640158a9bfcde005264e59e8d566781ab1415b139d2e4c603.7f2721073f19841be16f41b0a70b600ca6b880c8f3df6f3535cbc704371bdfa4.json`
- `8c8624b8ac8aa99c60c912161f8332de003484428c47906d7ff7eb7f73eecdbb.20430bd8e10ef77a7d2977accefe796051e01bc2fc4aa146bc862997a1a15e79`
- `8c8624b8ac8aa99c60c912161f8332de003484428c47906d7ff7eb7f73eecdbb.20430bd8e10ef77a7d2977accefe796051e01bc2fc4aa146bc862997a1a15e79.json`